# define multiple #defines with same value

Tags: c++, c

I have a few things that I want to #define.  Those are IN, OUT, ON, OFF, UP, and DOWN.  I want the IN, ON, and UP to be a '1', and the rest '0'.  Is there a way I can do something similar to this:

```
#define IN, ON, UP        1
#define OUT, OFF, DOWN    0
```

I know I can #define each on their own line, but I'm looking for a bit of compactness...

Edit:

Thanks for all the responses.  The reason for these `#define`s are that they are for states.  In my code I have stuff like this:

`TRISBbits.TRISB5 = IN;`
`if(PORTBbits.RB10 == ON)`
and `if(condition){someFlag = UP;}`

I should have clarified my usage of the `#define` statements.

Comment: Are you sure you want to #define them? There's probably a better way.

Comment: Make your code readable before making it compact.

Comment: Please don't overuse defines, especially if you are using c++

Comment: consider making them `const int`'s or better ENUMs

Comment: @Max:  Agreed.  I'm doing these to make my code more readable.  Instead of something like `TRISBbits.TRISB6 = 1;` I can do `TRISBbits.TRISB6 = IN;`.  The others are for output state and flag state, respectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know I can #define each on their own line, but I'm looking for a bit of compactness...

**No, you'll need to #define each macro separately.**

Macros are pretty simple -- the name comes first, and whatever else is on the line is the value. The compiler simply substitutes the value for the name wherever the name appears.

Comment: I have it that way right now, but I was looking at that downward string of 1s and 0s and thinking that I could condense it down a bit.

Answer (score 5):

You can only `#define` one item per line.

But please consider not using `#define`s at all.  A naieve approach would be to use `static const`s:

```
static const bool In = true, On = true, Up = true;
static const bool Out = false, Off = false, Down = false;
```

A better approach would be to out these in an unnamed `namespace`:

```
namespace
{
    const bool
        In = true,
        On = true,
        Up = true,
        Out = false,
        Off = false,
        Down = false;
};
```

This is superior than the `static const`s because anything in an anonymous namespace is effectively visible in the current translation unit only.  In other words, it won't pollute the global namespace.

Another alternative is to use `enum`s:

```
enum
{
  In = 1,
  On = 1,
  Up = 1,
  Out = 0,
  Off = 0,
  Down = 0
};
```

This is either superior or inferior to either of the two alternatives above depending on how you want to use it.  You can't take the address of an `enum`, for example.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the C++ way of doing the above is to use an unnamed namespace instead of the static keyword. OP has also included 'c' as a tag but if he's looking for a C++ solution unnamed namespaces are an alternative to the above.

Comment: @Muckle_ewe:  An unnamed `namespace` will make anything defined within it visible only in the translation unit where it is found.  In other words, it won't pollute the global namespace.  This is a generally good idea, and should probably be done by default.

Comment: I'm doing it in C. C++ tag was because of the I assumed `#define` works the same way in both languages.

Comment: @KZ5EE: `#define` works the same way in C and C++ (because it happens before the language even comes in to play), but C++ has more ways to get rid of this cruft than C does.

Comment: Wouldn't static also limit the variable to the current translation unit? Because this is as far as I know the only thing static does. (limiting or extending a variable to translation unit scope).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way and even if there is I'd advise against it as you would are likely to lose a lot of readability in your code with this.  Particularly with defines you want to make it clear what is defined as what

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant define #define like that.

But why dont you use const int.

you can do something like this:

```
static const int IN=1,ON=1,OP=1;
static const int OUT=0,OFF=0,DOWN=0;
```

Anyways one should try to avoid the #define, if they can be,  by using const variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with defines, but you can do it with `enum`. If three lines are acceptable, then this works without needing to explicitly using `0` and `1`:

```
enum { OUT, IN };
enum { OFF, ON };
enum { DOWN, UP };
```

This works because an `enum` will default the first name to have the value `0`, and subsequent names are given the value that is one greater than the one given before it (unless a value is explicitly specified with `=`). It is natural to group related names together in a single `enum`, so this provides an additional readability benefit.

In C, an `enum` has `int` type, so its behavior will be the same as your macro version. In C++, the behavior will likely be the same as well, since an `enum` is allowed to be implicitly converted to an `int`.

Comment: I had assumed that OP wanted the names to have specific values.  Moreover, there's no need to have 3 seperate enums here, far as I can tell.

Comment: @JohnDibling: `enum`s begin with `0`, and auto-increment. Three separate `enum`s allows the first name of each to start at `0`, and the second name to get the value `1`.

Comment: I'm aware of that.  However, what you may not realize is that you can assign specific values, as with `enum { Foo = 42 };`  And you can assign the same value to multiple names, as with: `enum { Foo = 42, Bar = 42 };`

Comment: @JohnDibling: I am aware. Everyone else has already provided that answer.

Comment: I think `enum`s are great, but I haven't had any luck using them without having to do a `typedef` for state checking.

Comment: @KZ5EE: You will need to show me evidence of that. I have never had a problem with C. C++ is different. See: http://ideone.com/qMGkZa